# Import and process daily csv dump from external SFTP into Marketing cloud data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sftp

Here's the case:
an external organization will produce a daily csv dump and we would like to process this file to a Marketing cloud data extension. We can set up the external SFTP (provided by the external organization) and import the file into the data extension via the import activity in automation studio. However we also have to remove it from the sftp after processing. Does anyone know if this is possible in an automation?

Or as another option would it be possible to rename or move the file to another folder for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible at the moment.

You might stumble upon information about a special data extract type called "Delete File From ET FTP or Safehouse" (that is not enabled by default) that allows you to delete from the following places:

- Export folder of your Enhanced FTP
- Import folder of your Enhanced FTP
- The Safehouse

Those are the only options supported currently - specifying a path is not possible nor can you select other "File Locations" that you would normally use.

We had a case with support trying to get an extract to delete a file from a different business unit and even that proved impossible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you have any idea if it is possible to restrict access on directory level (so only give access to a specific folder) on the enhanced FPT from marketing cloud itself?

Comment: @Michel Marketing Cloud does not allow such restrictions - you are only able to define if a user has only Read-only or Full Access. I based my answer on the presumption you need to delete the file from the external FTP, but if you need to remove it from the FTP of Marketing Cloud, the Data Extract can delete it that if you make sure that the file is in one of the locations above.

Comment: Indeed that is the preferred method (delete the file from the external FTP). However I was thinking of alternatives and using a specific directory with restricted access could have worked for us as well. But as this is also not possible I might need to think of other solutions. Thanks, michel